# Switching both power and ground

Tags: mosfet, switches

I had two sensor modules connected to my arduino, after some experiments i noticed that when the both modules are powered, i couldn't get correct readings from either one.
The Only case i got correct readings from one module happened when i switched OFF both power and ground for the other one

[image: That's how i did it]

It worked fine (although i didnt get the maximum readings from the sensor)

Now I am asking if i can substitute the BJTs with Mosfets to solve the problem of high voltage drops on BJTs (without using MOSFET driver)

Comment: Both Pin 2 and 3 use separate pull resistors to V+.e.g. 10k.... Q3 is Emitter Follower =Unity Gain high speed., Q4 = open collector ( high gain, lower speed (rise time) switch )  Pin 1 = 0V

Comment: You need to fix (or at least understand) the root cause problem and not put wallpaper over the cracks.

Comment: how high were the voltage drops you saw?

Comment: my question is can i switch both power and ground at the same time using MOSFETs?

Comment: @Andyaka it took me time to understand your comment (my poor language), thank you i got it